# As Ember 2.* uses Git when creating a new project, how do I create my own Git repo for my web app's development?

Tags: git, ember.js, github, ember-cli

When I run `ember new helloworld` using ember-cli, it downloads all of the initial building blocks for a new Ember project.

All of it is downloaded using Git. This means that, after finishing running the command for creating a new project, you are basically left with a clone of an official Ember repository.

I would like to create my own Git repository for creating my web app. How would I do this without interfering with or breaking what has been set up by ember-cli? Is it safe to delete the .git directory so I can make my own? Or is there a better/more correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is totally up to you if you want to start a new `git` repo. The installed ember app does not include any git origin . so , you are free to erase .`git` folder and start from scratch .

Answer (score 3):

First, create your empty Git repo wherever you want to host your code.

Second, create the Ember CLI app.

Third, set the upstream URL in the newly created Ember CLI app to the URL of your empty repo via:

```
git remote add origin http://the-url-of-your-repo
git push origin master
```

If you're hosting your project on GitHub, you can use their more detailed instructions:

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/